# Does ESXi 6.0 Support any PCIe x1 SATA RAID Controllers?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware-raid, sata

I'm trying to find a PCIe x1 SATA RAID controller, that is supported by ESXi 6.

I've spent hours searching the [ESXi compatibility site](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=io), however I have yet to come across one. Is this a fruitless search?

Comment: If its to run on an old motherboard, check if the CPU is fully supported.

Comment: I am currently looking into same controller, so far I can confirm such device exists - Adaptec RAID 6405E Storage Controller 2270800-R. It is Pci-e x1 and it is [supported by ESXi](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=io&productid=20867&deviceCategory=io&details=1&keyword=6405E&page=1&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc). It is not cheap, though, so I am looking into other options now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that a single sata port is 600MB/s and each PCIe lane can only carry 250MB/s (2.0) or 500MB/s (3.0) its unlikely that anyone would design such a bottlenecked raid card for enterprise.

Comment: Yup, makes sense. I'll try and move some other cards around and make some room in a different slot.